# How to reassign a array in c?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reasi(char** a){

    char* x[] = {"1","22","333"};
    a = x;
}


int main(){

    char* a[] = {"bob","alice","tom"};
    reasi(a);
    for(int i=0; i< 3; i++){

        printf("%s\n",a[i]);
    }
}
```

The desired output should be {"1","22","333"}, but it won't work if I assign the value like that. I do know how to change the value of an `int` or `char` but don't know how to reassign the value to an array (without dynamically allocating memory). I tried to update each element inside "a" and it works. Thank you.

Comment: You don't have a "2D" array. You have a simple normal "1D" array of pointers. And you can't assign to array, only *copy* to them. The naive way to solve your problem is a simple loop over the array `x` and assign each element to the corresponding element in `a`.

Comment: Use `memcpy` or a `for`-loop to copy arrays by value

Comment: But in either case (`memcpy` or `for` loop), you will need to pass a 2nd parameter containing the number of elements in `a`, e.g. `void reasi (char **a, size_t nelem) {...}` (or use a sentinel `NULL` at the end of `a`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `memcpy(a, x, sizeof x)` will do it, for this code

Comment: @M.M - right you are there. (though a hardcoded local is less than an optimal way to handle the data ... `:)`

Comment: Study arrays then pointers then functions then strings, in that order.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing won't work. You're simply creating a local array and then assigning your local parameter `a` to the beginning of this array (which changes nothing about the `a` in `main`). So the real thing isn't modified.

To actually modify this, you can either do a plain `for` loop:

```
// NOTE: this assumes array has the same number of elements as x
void reasi(char** a)
{
    char* x[] = {"1","22","333"};
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof x / sizeof *x; ++i)
        a[i] = x[i];
}
```

Or use `memcpy`:

```
#include <string.h>

// NOTE: this assumes array has the same number of elements as x
void reasi(char** a)
{
    char* x[] = {"1","22","333"};
    memcpy(a, x, sizeof x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array is not a 2D array. By seeing your code I assume you mistaken 1D array for 2D array, hence I will answer according to it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reasi(char** a){

     a[0] = "1";
     a[1] = "22";
     a[2] = "333";
}


int main()
{
    char* a[] = {"bob","alice","tom"};
    reasi(a);
    for(int i=0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",a[i]);
    }
}
```

This will give you your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

In C an array has a fixed size. You cannot resize it after the fact. If the size always stays the same, you can copy the new array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reasi(char const **a) {
  char const *x[] = {"1", "22", "333"};
  memcpy(a, x, sizeof x);
}

int main() {
  char const *a[] = {"bob", "alice", "tom"};
  reasi(a);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    puts(a[i]);
}
```

If you do want to resize the array, you are going to have to allocate it dynamically with `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Both `a` and `x` are each an *array of pointers to* `char`. In C, you cannot assign the contents of an array [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) `"the array object ... is not an lvalue."`

Instead, you must assign each element (pointer) from `x` to `a` or use `memcpy()` to accomplish the same.

Further, hardcoding the contents of `x` in your function makes little sense. Why? You have just written a function that does nothing but assign the pointers (to String-Literals `"1"`, `"22"`, `"333"`) and is incapable of doing anything else -- useful.

Why not declare `x` in `main()` and pass it as a parameter along with `a` and the number of elements? That way, you can pass any *array of pointers to* `char` as `x` (with at least 3 elements) and reassign the elements to `a`).

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reasi (char **a, char **x, size_t nelem)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nelem; i++) {
        a[i] = x[i];
    }
}

int main() {

    char *a[] = {"bob","alice","tom"},
         *x[] = {"1","22","333"},
         *y[] = {"4","55","666","7777","8888"};
    size_t n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;
    
    reasi (a, x, n);
    
    puts ("x->a");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("%s\n", a[i]);
    }
    
    reasi (a, y, n);
    
    puts ("\ny->a");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("%s\n", a[i]);
    }
    
    reasi (a, y + 2, n);
    
    puts ("\ny+2->a");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("%s\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

The refactoring above generalizes your `reasi()` function, making it reusable and a bit more useful than a single use case of `"1"`, `"22"`, `"333"`.

**Example Use/Output**

Running you get the expected:

```
$ ./bin/reasi
x->a
1
22
333

y->a
4
55
666

y+2->a
666
7777
8888
```

Wrapping `memcpy()` in a function in that case wouldn't buy you any benefit, you could simply call `memcpy (a, x, n * sizeof *a);` from `main()` and avoid the function call overhead (which a decent compiler would likely optimize out anyway).

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Huh, I always thought an array was a non-modifiable lvalue. So if it's not an lvalue then do you happen to know what it is?

Comment: An array is its own special object type in C. It is not an lvalue. It can be initialized with a brace-initializer, but after initialization, the "array" itself (e.g. the pointer the array is converted to on-access) is not an lvalue.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, arrays decays to pointers into pretty much all contexts. Thus it is not possible to use it as l-value. However if the array was embedded into a structure `struct { int A[5]; }` then the structure could be used as l-value. It would mimic an assignable array

Comment: Yes, agreed, but the embedded struct can only be assigned to using a brace-initializer when the struct is declared, just as when the array is declared. After that time, you still would not be able to assign another array to the embedded array to change the objects it contains.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think you could use a compound literal for the `struct` to come close to that (using initializer multiple times). Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/EnaP5qxoh). Wouldn't work on an anonymous `struct` though.